# VBScript Outlook encounters encrypted email producing error 'Entrust Entelligence Security Provider'

Tags: email, encryption, vbscript, outlook, hta

I have an `HTA` and using `VBScript` to loop through `Outlook` email folders and get folder size. The `HTA` is run on a shared drive by staff, it is not an administrator tool. On occasion, my company will send encrypted emails. When the `VBS` hits one of these emails, the following happens:

1) `VBS` pauses.

2) Outlook displays the 'Entrust Entelligence Security Provider' error and asks the user to click 'OK'.

3) Once OK is clicked, the `VBS` continues.

The Outlook message does not bring focus to Outlook, so it is possible the user will not notice the message and continue to wait for the `VBS` to finish. 
Is there any way of avoiding this message?
Here is my code:

```
public TotalSize
Sub OutlookDetail
    TotalSize = 0
    msgbox "Depending on the size of your Outlook account, this process may take up to 60 seconds" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
        "If you have encrypted emails, Outlook will make a sound and give you the 'Entrust Entelligence Security Provider' message. Click 'OK' to proceed."

    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each objItem in colItems
        'THE OUTLOOK ERROR MAY OCCUR HERE
            TotalSize = TotalSize + objItem.Size
    Next

    Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    GetSubfolders(objInbox)
    msgbox "The size of Inbox and all Subfolders: " & Round((TotalSize / 1048576),2) & " MB"
End Sub

Sub GetSubfolders(objParentFolder)
    Set colFolders = objParentFolder.Folders
        For Each objFolder in colFolders
            Set objSubfolder = objParentFolder.Folders(objFolder.Name)

        intSize = 0
        Set colItems = objSubfolder.Items
            For Each objItem in colItems 
        'THE OUTLOOK ERROR MAY ALSO OCCUR HERE
        intSize = intSize + objItem.size
        next
        TotalSize = TotalSize + intSize
            GetSubfolders objSubfolder
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What line of code throws a dialog window?

Comment: `TotalSize = TotalSize + objItem.Size` is where the error will occur if the email is encrypted. As soon as I attempt to get an attribute (size, body, subject, recipients, etc.), Outlook will produce an error. Sorry for late response. But I still have not found a solution.